# My custom css is not working in print invoice

Tags: css, printing

I'm working on page which has custom css and I wanted to print that page but its not working for me.
    `@media print {background-color:red !important;}`
This media print is not working for me. I'm trying all those possibility which are already on stackoverflow but non of these work.

```js
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

```css
      body {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            }

            .seat_no{
                border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
                padding: 4px 8px !important;
                color: black !important;
                display: block;
                font-size: 19px !important;
                cursor: pointer;
                visibility: visible;
                page-break-inside: auto !important;
                display: block !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;

            }
            .table thead{
                background: #585a6b !important;
                color: #fff !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            }
            .booked {
                background-color: #296090 !important;
                visibility: visible;
                page-break-inside: auto !important;
                display: inline block !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            }
```

```html
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary print-invoice-btn mt " onclick="PrintInvoice('print-invoice')" >Print Details</button>
```

Comment: whats the error code or can you post your full code or a working example?

Comment: i didn't get my css in print. i only want to show a background color on print page

Comment: i use class="booked" as shown in Question

Answer (score 0):

`@media print {background-color:red !important;}` is not the valid. Correct syntax is -like this:

```
@media print {
  div {
    background-color: red
  }
}
```

Here is an example for you:

```css
@media print{
  * {
    color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
    box-sizing: border-box
  }

  div {
    background-color: #424953;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10% 0
  }

  button {
    background-color: #4B89DA;
    color: #F4F6F9;
    width: 50%;
    border: solid 2px #F4F6F9;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="window.print();">Click me to see the changes!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: in my case @media print is not working my div class name is booked and it has a background-color which is not working

Comment: i have to print a bootstrap table and the td's of table has a background color

Comment: i using internal and inline css